# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{Mf(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification

While studying the proof to Laplace's Method I thought about the following claim:

> $$\int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}e^{f(x)} < +\infty \implies \int \limits_{0}^{+\infty}e^{Mf(x)} < +\infty, \hspace{5mm} M\geq1$$

**My attempt**

If $f$ is continuous, then we may consider the inverse image under $e^{f}$ of $]1, +\infty[$. Call it $U$. By the definition of continuity and by the standard topology of $\Bbb R$, $U$ is just a collection of intervals, therefore we can consider their cumulative length $L(U)$. It is clear that $L(U)$ must be finite, for otherwise the hypothesis would be contradicted. Therefore $e^{Mf}$ is less or equal than $e^{f}$ on $\Bbb R - L(U)$ and it is greater only on a subset of $\Bbb R$ of finite length, so that one can show the convergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{Mf(x)}$ by invoking the Comparison Test.

My question is now whether is there a proof to the same claim which does not require $f$ to be continuous or whether there is a counter-example. Also, is the idea behind my proof correct?

---

As always any comment or answer is much approcciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: isn't this just a special case of the fact that a product of integrable functions is integrable?

Comment: @user1090793: Even for noninteger $M$?

Comment: @user1090793 As pointed out above $M$ may not be an integer and what you say is true for proper integration but not for improper integration. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1065538/998769

Comment: @JacobManaker: ah, I should have realized OP meant $M$ a real number greater than or equal to 1. Of course, for $f(x) = \log(\frac{1}{x^2})$, $M = 1/2$ yields a function that is no longer integrable on the given interval.